# Why my data cannot be saved into MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication

I try to sign up, i submit the form then it logs me `undefined`, and it doesn't save the user into the database, even the code from the tutorial works perfectly.
Here's my code

```
exports.postSignup = (req, res, next) => {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    const confirmPassword = req.body.confirmPassword;
    User.findOne({ email: email })
      .then(userDoc => {
        if (userDoc) {
          return res.redirect('/signup');
        }
        const user = new User({
          email: email,
          password: password,
          cart: { items: [] }
        });
        return user.save();
      })
      .then(result => {
        res.redirect('/login');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
```

I have to mention that the user model is correct.

Comment: Do you store the password as clear text? You should **never** (including prototype and learning) do this, store hash values. Maybe have a look at http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/

Comment: Its a part of the course, I will hash em with bcrypt later

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure, but in my own code I dont save an object within the return line.

Maybe try this

```ja
exports.postSignup = (req, res, next) => {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    const confirmPassword = req.body.confirmPassword;
    User.findOne({ email: email })
      .then(userDoc => {
        if (userDoc) {
          return res.redirect('/signup');
        }
        const user = new User({
          email: email,
          password: password,
          cart: { items: [] }
        });
        try{
            user.save();
        }catch(err){
            res.send(err);
        }
        return user; //only if you want to return a user ofc
      })
```

Other things that maybe going on:

- Is your ip whitelisted?
- Did you include the connection string?
- Do you return a jason object? then make sure to use a parser in your middleware.

Comment: Yes, it is, yes, also included the string but i dont work with json so far, in the course works flawless but here is a whole other story..

Comment: if non of my suggestions worked, i learned building a restapi with crud functionality form this guy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vjf774RKrLc&t=1446s
He codes in a different way but the essence is the same.